# php DateTime seems to be acting up sorry for reasking no answers seem to be working

Tags: php, datetime

so im simply trying to keeps statistic on a system im writing although when trying to get the difference of the two dates.. i know this topic has been covered many times however i have tried using date diff and strtotime and keep getting errors what am i doing wrong

```
$s_date = mysql_result($ticket_result, $t, 's_date');
$d_date = strtotime($s_date);
$d_today = strtotime($today);
$ds_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $d_date);
$d = $ds_date->diff($ds_date);
```

both the $s_date and $today were generated using date('Y-m-d H:i:s')

when i try to make a new DateTime and i get an exeption and when i do it this way i get a different error saying calling diff to non-object im sorry to ask again but ive tried everything from here i dont know what im doing wrong

Comment: About half of your text here is repeated apologies for asking the question. Consider removing that, and adding more detail about your error(s) instead.

Comment: You're attempting to call `diff` on a string. Post the code **and error messages** from your `DateTime` attempt.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `$s_date` and `$today` are suitable date/time strings...

```
$d_date = new DateTime($s_date);

// if you actually want a "now" time, just omit the constructor argument
$d_today = new DateTime($today);
```

If you know the format of the strings, I prefer using `DateTime::createFromFormat` as it removes ambiguity around date strings in non-US locales, eg

```
// say $s_date is in the format m/d/Y H:i:s
$d_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y H:i:s', $s_date);
```

Now, assuming you want actually the difference between the `$today` date and `$d_date`...

```
$diff = $d_date->diff($d_today);
```

Comment: this is very similar to what i tried before although you answered another question i had which was creating a formatted date time i was doing date('Y-m-d H:i:s') then a new datetime($date) and it wasnt working i see why now ill let u know if this works thanks